# Dart/Flutter PostFrameCallBack and Uri.base.origin

Tags: flutter, dart, callback

I am trying to implement a system where the user will call out to an external website for the log in and be sent back the key in the url. If I call this block of code while this screen of the app as the home called in Main.dart it works exactly as intended: the code checks if 'token' is in the URL and if not it will redirect to the external site for user log in, retrieves the key and gets sent back to the flutter screen where it can now find the token when it does initState().

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static final routeName = "/login";
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  var tempToken;
        @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            final currentUrl = Uri.base;
            print(currentUrl);
            if (currentUrl.queryParameters['token'] == null) {
              print('looking for token');
              // You are not connected so redirect to the login
              WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
                html.window.location.assign(
                  'http://localhost:8080/auth/?source=app&after=${base64Encode(utf8.encode(currentUrl.origin))}', //where i send in the redirect back
                );
              });
            } else {
              tempToken = currentUrl.queryParameters['token'].toString();
              print(tempToken);
            }
          }
    
       @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
```

**The Problem**
The problem arises when I try to go to this screen as a redirect from the welcome screen of my app. The way the code is set up it will send me back to currentUrl which will be '/' instead of '/login' sending me to the welcome screen with the token no longer in the url to be found. Any idea of where I should go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we have found useful to grab the full `href` as soon as the Flutter web app starts, with code like this:

```
Map<String, String>? initialQueryParameters;

void main() {
  initialQueryParameters = getHref().queryParameters;
  runApp(const Controller());
}
```

This captures the value of any query parameters before you create the `MaterialApp` and it starts routing to pages, which will change the `href`.

Our flow is:

- index.html
- some oauth website, which redirects back to
- index.html?someParam=someValue (or could be index.html/#/route?...)

When the Flutter app runs for the first time, someParam is null. After the redirection back, the app runs for a second time, but now someParam is set to someValue. Because this was grabbed at startup and stored in the global `initialQueryParameters` it can be checked whenever needed and is available even after routing and navigation may rewrite the href.